# How do I change the direction my sprite is facing based on if they're moving left or right?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to change my code so that when my sprite is moving to the left, they are facing left, and when they're moving to the right, they're facing right.Here is my code without me trying to implement the flipping feature:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpForce;

    public KeyCode left;
    public KeyCode right;
    public KeyCode jump;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    public Transform groundCheckPoint;

    public bool isGrounded;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;

    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheckPoint.position, groundCheckRadius, whatIsGround);
        

        if(Input.GetKey(left))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        } else if(Input.GetKey(right))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        } else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(jump) && isGrounded)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(jump) && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.8f);
        }
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,transform.localScale.y,transform.localScale.z);
    }

    
}
```

I've looked at several tutorials, however, none of them seem to work, and I think it's because I used a different script for making my player move, so when I try to use another tutorial for making the player flip, I don't correctly integrate what the tutorial says with what I already have.

Comment: transform.localScale = new Vector3(1 or -1 based on direction,transform.localScale.y,transform.localScale.z); should do it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! I put what you did, but it only flips the character one time(when I first enter the game) rather than change direction based on whether I'm moving left or right. Do you have an idea of what I should do about that/what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your new code?

Comment: okay, just edited!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, you may have already gotten it. You need to set it in the if statements, so that it goes to 1 or -1 depending on the direction it is moving, and the bottom, it will simply set it to -1 regardless of direction which obviously does not help.

Comment: haha, I realized that a bit after I edited my post, but thanks! One more question though, I want my character to have a weapon, and made a fire point in front of the character, however, when the character switches sides, the fire point stays in the same place instead of changing with the character. I tried using rotate instead, but the outcome becomes weird and flips a bunch of times even when I'm moving one direction. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Hmm, is the fire point gameobject a child of the player? If so, it should scale with it.

Comment: Yes, it is a child of the player, and i figured it out! I just accidentally made a typo in the script that caused the object to act weird, but when I fixed that, it scaled as it should.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's do a cleanup on that mess. General rule of programming: if you have if-elses all around, you maybe doing something wrong and there is easier way:

```
Vector2 input;
float _movementForceMultiplier;
float _maxVelocityMagnitude;

Update()
{
    Vector2 input = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0);
    ...
}

FixedUpdate()
{
    _rigidbody.AddForce(input * _movementForceMultiplier * Time.fixedDeltaTime, ForceMode.Force);
    Vector3 currentVelocity = _rigidbody.velocity;
    if (currentVelocity.sqrMagnitude > _maxVelocityMagnitude* _maxVelocityMagnitude)
    {
        Vector3 velocityLimited = _rigidbody.velocity.normalized * _maxVelocityMagnitude;
        _rigidbody.velocity = velocityLimited;
    }
    ...
}
```

_movementForceMultiplier together with Rigidbody's drag and PhysicMaterial settings are your way to manipulate player's acceleration, and only then you may want to restrict the resulting velocity using _maxVelocityMagnitude (squared for comparison because .magnitude is heavier to calculate than .sqrMagnitude), but never, please, never set velocity directly until you're understanding why you need this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response and for the tips! If I'm being honest, I'm still a bit confused- first, in the update method, how would I do the same thing for vertical movement? Would I just create another Vector 2 variable and assign it the same way as horizontal? Also, do you think you could explain the velocity with a bit more, I'm having trouble understanding it. I also wanted to know if I still need the isGrounded mechanisms- I was using it to make restrict the character to only jump once.

Comment: First, the jump is an instant event (key press), while the movement is a constant input. So, in Update() you just catch if jump key pressed, and if bool _canJump is true, you flip the bool _isJumpPressed and _canJump (maybe use int instead to count remaining jumps, if you want to jump mid air). Then in FixedUpdate() you call _rigidbody.AddForce with ForceMode.Impulse.

Comment: Second, the ground check - its better to set collider on your player and use OnTriggerEnter to check for _isGrounded there instead of doing sphere cast, its just more convenient. Don't forget to assign Ground and Player objects to corresponding layers and set collisions between them in Project Settings/Physics. Third, the velocity: it is a vector that represents the movement of a rigidbody and despite you able to manupulate it, you better not to because physics engine is doing it for you already. Here is what Unity says about it: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Comment: And few more general advises: make your operations as small and simple as possible, split everything into methods and name them properly. Its much better to have 12 small methods in class than two huge. Write code in same order as it should happen, maintain clear control flow (its when you reading code and it doesn't confusing you by jumping back and forth), don't be afraid to introduce a class to extract behavior to it - maybe you should go and do so for jump mechanics, that way you'll be able to easily improve or replace it without messing with movement or attack mechanics.

Comment: Things will not come instantly to you and its okay, you'll be feelign confused and its okay too :)
Keep coding and stay awesome!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I just started out with game development and even though I do have some previous experience with coding, it's definitely difficult, at least for me, to make all the code work without resorting to some bad practices. I'll definitely keep it up though, you're inspiring :)